# Postgres query row with dot notaiton to build a nested json as query result

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a flat table with dot-notationed columns, similar to the following:

| title.en | title.fr | category.name.en | category.name.fr | category.acronym.en | category.acronym.fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| English Title | French Title | English Category Name | French Category Name | English Category Acronym | French Category Acronym |

the dot notations are there to inidicate a nested object, so each dot makes a nesting level of json. According to this, I want to be able to query this result from the table in json(b):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "title": {
      "en": "English Title",
      "fr": "French Title"
    },
    "category": {
      "name": {
        "en": "English Category Name",
        "fr": "French Category Name"
      },
      "acronym": {
        "en": "English Category Acronym",
        "fr": "French Category Acronym"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's possible to manually do this using nested "jsonb_build_object" functions, but want to know if it's possible to shortcut it using dot notations in column names.

Comment: You can have column names in dot notation, but you **must enclose then in double quotes (")**. Then they work exactly the same as standard column names. Dot notation holds no special meaning/function.  IMHO it really is a bad idea; lots of work for no gain.

Comment: @Belayer but the format is not my real concern, I can use underscore ("_") rather than dot or any other convention. I just need to know the method, or have a function to query flat table as nested json, the dot notation is used is just to indicate how the nesting should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that `data` is the table name.
The solution below requires several steps :

**1. Get the column names from the database schema :**

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'data'
```

Result :

| table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| data | title.en |
| data | title.fr |
| data | category.name.en |
| data | category.name.fr |
| data | category.acronym.en |
| data | category.acronym.fr |

**2. Convert the dot-notationed column names into the target jsonb format :**

```
SELECT ('{"' || table_name || '": {"' || replace(column_name, '.', '": {"') || '": "' || column_name || '"' || repeat('}', regexp_count(column_name, '\.')+2)) :: jsonb
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'data'
```

Result :

| jsonb |
| --- |
| {"data": {"title": {"en": "title.en"}}} |
| {"data": {"title": {"fr": "title.fr"}}} |
| {"data": {"category": {"name": {"en": "category.name.en"}}}} |
| {"data": {"category": {"name": {"fr": "category.name.fr"}}}} |
| {"data": {"category": {"acronym": {"en": "category.acronym.en"}}}} |
| {"data": {"category": {"acronym": {"fr": "category.acronym.fr"}}}} |

**3. Merge the jsonb column names all together to build the final jsonb template :**

In this step, we need to create a specific `aggregate` function `jsonb_merge_agg` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(x jsonb, y jsonb) RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql AS $$
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg
           ( COALESCE(x1->>'key', y1->>'key')
           , CASE
               WHEN x1->>'key' IS NULL THEN y1->'value'
               WHEN y1->>'key' IS NULL THEN x1->'value'
               WHEN jsonb_typeof(x1->'value') = 'object' AND jsonb_typeof(y1->'value') = 'object' THEN jsonb_merge(x1->'value', y1->'value')
               ELSE jsonb_build_array(x1->'value', y1->'value')
             END
           )
    FROM jsonb_path_query(x,'$[*].keyvalue()') AS x1
    FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_path_query(y,'$[*].keyvalue()') AS y1
      ON y1->>'key' = x1->>'key' ;
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE jsonb_merge_agg(x jsonb)
(stype = jsonb, sfunc = jsonb_merge) ;

SELECT jsonb_merge_agg(('{"' || table_name || '": {"' || replace(column_name, '.', '": {"') || '": "' || column_name || '"' || repeat('}', regexp_count(column_name, '\.')+2)) :: jsonb) AS jsonb_template
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'data'
```

Result :

| jsonb_template |
| --- |
| {"data": {"title": {"en": "title.en", "fr": "title.fr"}, "category": {"name": {"en": "category.name.en", "fr": "category.name.fr"}, "acronym": {"en": "category.acronym.en", "fr": "category.acronym.fr"}}}} |

**4. Replace in the jsonb_template every column name by the corresponding value :**

In this step, we need to create another specific aggregate function `replace_agg` based on the standard `replace` function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace(x text, y text, old text, new text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql AS $$
SELECT replace(COALESCE(x, y), old, new) ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE replace_agg(x text, old text, new text)
(stype = text, sfunc = replace) ;
```

**5. Build the final query :**

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT jsonb_merge_agg(('{"' || table_name || '": {"' || replace(column_name, '.', '": {"') || '": "' || column_name || '"' || repeat('}', regexp_count(column_name, '\.')+2)) :: jsonb) AS jsonb_template
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'data'
)
SELECT replace_agg( l.jsonb_template :: text
                  , content->>'key'
                  , content->>'value'
                  ) AS final_result
  FROM list AS l
 CROSS JOIN data AS d
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(to_jsonb(d), '$.keyvalue()') AS content
 GROUP BY d
```

Final Result :

| final_result |
| --- |
| {"data": {"title": {"en": "English Title", "fr": "French Title"}, "category": {"name": {"en": "English Category Name", "fr": "French Category Name"}, "acronym": {"en": "English Category Acronym", "fr": "French Category Acronym"}}}} |

all the test results in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7TtcCGOM)